# How to reproject .las file from known EPSG (6499) to a custom coordinate system with WKT?

Tags: epsg, well-known-text, las, pdal

I am trying to use PDAL ([filters.reprojection](https://pdal.io/PDAL.pdf)) to convert a .las file from a known EPSG:6499 to a custom projection.  Can I just put my WKT string into the pipline?

```
"type":"filters.reprojection",
"in_srs":"EPSG:6499",
"out_srs":"my_WKT_string_goes _here?"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing PDAL with OSGEO4W Shell "setup" I was able to run the following testpipe1.json file with

`pdal pipeline "C:\TEST\testpipe1.json"`

```
{
    "pipeline":[
     {
        "type":"readers.las",
        "filename":"F:\\MP02-MP25\\LAS\\25_RGB (1016).las"
       
      },
      {
        "type":"filters.reprojection",
        "in_srs":"EPSG:4438",
        "out_srs":"+proj=omerc +lat_0=40.8333333333333 +lonc=-74 +alpha=58 +gamma=58 +k=0.99999 +x_0=457200 +y_0=457200 +ellps=GRS80 +units=ft +no_defs +type=crs"
      },
      {
        "type":"writers.las",       
        "filename":"F:\\MP02-MP25\\LAS\\25_RGB (1016)T.las"
      }
    ]
  }
```